# How choose among Android Library Project and jar file

Tags: android

I do use quite a lot of external Android libraries, especially the open source.

The open source project authors, maybe sometimes provide a final compiled jar file.

However, most of the time, I will choose to use the library, as Android Library Project, by importing their source code.

I have an assumption that, the build system (with ProGuard) can better optimize of the APK file, if I provide the build system a complete set of source code files.

However, I'm not sure my assumption hold true?

**Is there any technical details study, to proof Android Library Project and jar file is better (Or vice-verse)**? So far, I don't find Google's official stand on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it does not matter if you use a `android-library` project or a `jar` file.

Proguard can obfuscate and optimize both.

The only reason why I see someone would go for a library-project instead of a jar is because the library contains resources(images, layouts, strings, dimens etc.).
A jar cannot have resources.

But with `aar`, it completely removes the need of library project, as `aar` can contain code and resources.

Currently, the only reason I use a library-project is when I want to modify some parts of the library or if I make frequent changes to it.